# What is the effect of heavy computation on `Timer.periodc` ( or `setInterval`)

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, event-loop, single-threaded

I was wondering what is the effect of heavy computation on `Timer.periodc` which often happens when making bots doing at an heavy task and at the same time running a job at a regular interval.

So I made this code but the results confused me.

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  asyncAwait();
}

int now() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

void asyncAwait() {
  int x = 0;
  int previousElapase = now();
  final programStart = now();
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    x++;
    final stepStart = now();
    final step = stepStart - previousElapase;
    print("$x at ${stepStart - programStart}ms Diff: ${x == 1 ? null : step}");
    previousElapase = stepStart;
    if (x == 5) {
      print("Timer cancelled");
      timer.cancel();
    }
  });
  final start = now();
  int i = 0;
  while (i++ < 10000000000);
  print("Heavy computation took in ${now() - start}");
}
```

On my system dart (2.13.0), here is the output

```
dart main.dart


Heavy computation took in 5988
1 at 5997ms Diff: null
2 at 6005ms Diff: 8 // Suspicious, confusing
3 at 7007ms Diff: 1002
4 at 8007ms Diff: 1000
5 at 9007ms Diff: 1000
Timer cancelled
```

My issue is here:

```
2 at 6005ms Diff: 8 // Suspicious, confusing
```

Why the second iteration happens (almost) immediately after the first ?

Can someone explain me what the compiler does step by step ?

My expectation is as follow

```
Schedule first at: 1000ms
Do heavy computation
Now is: 5988ms
[print Heavy computation took in 5988]
Now is: 5997ms
Now is same/after first schedule so add Timer periodic call back at the bottom of the Event loop Queue
Schedule second at: 6997ms
Do first task on event loop queue
[print 1 at 5997ms Diff: null]
Nothing to do, wait for next schedule of 6997ms
Now is 6997ms
Now is same/after second schedule so add Timer periodic call back at the bottom of the Event loop Queue
Schedule third at: 7997ms
Do second task on event loop queue
[print 2 at 6997ms Diff: 1000]
Nothing to do, wait for next schedule of 7997ms
and so on ...
```

At least that's how I think I understand how TimerPeriodic interacts with the Event, can someone correct me ?

I even rewrote the same program Javascript since it is single-threaded and I confirm that my expectation is correct (at least in Js)

```
let now = ()=> new Date().getTime();
let x = 0;
let previousElapase = now();
let programStart = now();

let timer = setInterval(()=> {
    x++;
    let stepStart = now();
    let step = stepStart - previousElapase;
    console.log(`${x} at ${stepStart - programStart}ms Diff: ${x === 1 ? null : step}`);
    previousElapase = stepStart;
    if (x === 5) {
        console.log(`Timer cancelled`);
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
let start = now();
let i = 0;
while (i++ < 10000000000);
console.log(`Heavy computation took in ${now() - start}`);
```

JavaScript output:

```
Heavy computation took in 11249
1 at 11256ms Diff: null
2 at 12258ms Diff: 1002
3 at 13262ms Diff: 1004
4 at 14264ms Diff: 1002
5 at 15265ms Diff: 1001
Timer cancelled
```

Comment: check `Timer.periodic` official docs, they say: *"The exact timing depends on the underlying timer implementation. No more than n callbacks will be made in duration * n time, but the time between two consecutive callbacks can be shorter and longer than duration."*

Comment: I don't know a thing about dart, but note that even your JS is entirely dependent on the environment where it's being ran (timers are not part of EcmaScript, they are environment dependent). Chrome for instance uses a currently non-standard implementation that does self-correct its drift. So in this browser you will actually have about the same behavior as your dart script: https://jsfiddle.net/f6argn0x/ However Firefox and node (and HTML specs) still do use a recursive timeout for setInterval, in these environments you will have your expected behavior.